# How to keep 'format on save', but prevent VScode from breaking line when saving HTML file?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When saving an HTML file it automatically separates my code into new lines (for better readability?). I'm also using Prettier extension. I want to keep format when save, but no line break. Already tried to tweak both VScode & Prettier config, but no success yet. Anyone has any idea why this happens?[This happens btw with other elements as well, but it seems like only when there are multiple attributes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIzuH.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior for Prettier. You can try to override the Prettier config print width (default 80) to a larger number, .i.e 200. This will prevent Prettier from breaking your lines, although it is not recommended. You might want to play around with this number until you find what works for you. Other setting you might want to apply is `bracketSameLine: true` this will put the closing bracket at the end of the last line instead of being alone on the next line. An example `.prettierrc` file with this config is:

```
{
  "printWidth": 200,
  "bracketSameLine": true
}
```